# arguments labels do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, swift3

```
if let player = playerDetailsViewController.player {
players.append(player)

let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: players.count-1, inSection: 0) <<error line
tableView.insertRows(at:[indexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)}
```

Comment: Please add few more details.

Comment: The first hit for [`[swift3] NSIndexPath forRow`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift3%5D+NSIndexPath+forRow) answers your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: players.count-1, section: 0)
```

and delete the `as IndexPath` bridge cast.

Comment: Now it works.. Thanks man...